# Не работает assert

Tags: python

выдает ошибку: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

```
def test(num):
    assert num > 0
    print(str(num))

a = input()

test(a)
```

Comment: test(int(a)) или test(float(a))

Comment: `>` не поддерживается между строками и числами. `input()` возвращает строку, вы ее передаете в функцию и сравниваете с `0`

Answer (score 2):

Input возвращает str. А str и int сравнивать нельзя. Поэтому:

```
def test(num):
    assert int(num) > 0
    print(num)

a = input()

test(a)
```

Если в input() нужно вносить дробные значения меньше одного, то можно вместо int использовать float.